# Spring framework - upgrade to 5.1 @import not working

Tags: spring

I was using spring version 5.0.9 and I had 2 configuration classes like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:commonServices.properties"}, encoding="UTF-8", ignoreResourceNotFound=false)
@Import(value= {DbCacheConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"...."})
public class DbConfig {
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class DbCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
}
```

All worked pretty good. When I started my test class or my JUnit test the DbCacheConfig class was called and then all was OK.

I just upgraded Spring version to 5.1.0 and nothing else. In this case the `@Import` seems to not be seen. In fact the `DbCacheConfig` is not created.

I can't figure why.... do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please add your test class.

Comment: I’ll add it later when I’m at office.... thank you! :)

Comment: @M.Deinum I created a sample project here https://github.com/angeloimm/spring_upgrade where you can reproduce the behaviour. Thank you

Comment: Whats with all the excludes? Looks like you arre excluding the world. Also why would you need `@EnableCaching`? Looks like you are using that to eagerly init caches in hibernate...  Which is actually the reason why it breaks as the `LocalSessionFactory` has no way of knowing that it needs to wait for the `CacheManager` to be initialized it just starts, however due to your hack it needs a dependency. Either add the `CacheManager` as an method argument or add an `@DependsOn("cacheManager")` to the `sessionFactory` method.

Comment: I added exclusions simply because I don't want to duplicate libraries (I know maven can handle it and can omit with no problems the duplicated libs but it's my personal habit). The point here is why if I use spring 5.0.9 the cache manager is called before the hibernate configuration while if i use spring 5.1 it's not so. I know i can add `@DependsOn` but why is it not ncessary in spring 5.0.9?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee in the order in which beans are loaded/started and that can change between Spring versions. However the real issue that you are basically using a hack which you shouldn't, it worked by shear luck in an older version not by design.

Comment: OK OK... I was thinking about it and I agree with you... It was my mistake and I have been lucky in the past :) Sorry and thank you

Comment: Well there have been changes with regards to `@Import` but only in the field of detecting nested `@Configuration` class. So that doesn't apply, another thing that changed is the fact that the `CacheManager` is now only build at the moment it is needed (for performance and scanning reasons). But as you aren't really using the cache manager (at least not here) it will never be initialized. Even if it would it could still be initialized after the `SessionFactory` bean. If you depend on beans you want to make that explicit so that spring can define the order of bean init.

Comment: Another thing regarding the excludes don't as it adds nothing but unclarity. If you want to force a specific version of library use the `dependencyManagement` section. The only exclude you need/want is probably `commons-logging` although that shouldn't be a problem either.